# How to create a page tab for a specific work items type?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I am building a new [page tab extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-workitem-extension?view=azure-devops#add-a-page) for Azure DevOps. I would like the new tab to only show on

**test cases** work items type like this:

[image]

Following their documentation, the new page tab is added to **all** work items. Maybe I missed something from another part of their documentation?

Here is my contribution manifest:

```
 {  
        "id": "sample-work-item-form-page",
        "type": "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form-page",
        "description": "Custom work item form page",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "My Page",
            "uri": "form-tab.html",
            "categories": ["Azure Test Plan"]
        } 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you didn't miss any steps.

Generally, we will define the scope and type in the extension manifest file.

From this doc about the [manifest reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops), I am afraid that there is no such definition could  specify a specific type of work item.

**Workaround:**

You could navigate to `Organization Settings -> Process -> Target process ->Edit Work item` and use the `Hide from layout` option to hide the tab for the work item type.

[image]

Here is [a discussion about this feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk/issues/16), you may refer to it.

> We considered letting the extension author specify this in their JSON
> manifest but that is too limiting since users will soon be able to
> create custom work item types and an extension author would never know
> what those are.

Hope this helps.